# How to generate unique layout with list of items using css grid?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, while-loop, css-grid

Basically I get a list of posts in an array and I'm trying to create a layout which is not just wrapping  into row outside the while loop. Each column is different.

This is the layout I'm trying to get.

[image]

I've got everything working apart from the section inside red border.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```css
ul.posts {
  display: grid;
  padding-left: 0px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  justify-content: between;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
ul.posts li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: "g1";
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/13;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: "g2";
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/7;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: "g3";
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 7/13;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 3/4;
  grid-column: 1/5;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 3/4;
  grid-column: 5/9;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 3/4;
  grid-column: 9/13;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(7) {
  grid-row: 4/5;
  display: flex;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(7) div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(7) div:nth-child(1) img {
  width: 100% !important;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(7) div:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row: 5/6;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(9) {
  grid-row: 4/6;
  grid-column: 7/13;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(9) img {
  height: 800px;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(10) {
  grid-row: 6/7;
  grid-column: 1/13;
}
ul.posts li:nth-child(11) {
  grid-row: 7/8;
  grid-column: 1/13;
}
ul.posts img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="posts">
          <li>
            <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
            <div class="description">
              <h2>Title 1</h2>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
            <div class="description">
              <h2>Title 2</h2>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
            <div class="description">
              <h2>Title 3</h2>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
              <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
            <div class="description">
              <h2>Title 4</h2>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
            <div class="description">
              <h2>Title 5</h2>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
            <div class="description">
              <h2>Title 6</h2>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
            <div class="description">
              <h2>Title 7</h2>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
            <div class="description">
              <h2>Title 8</h2>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </li>
            <li>
            <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
            <div class="description">
              <h2>Title 9</h2>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
            <div class="description">
              <h2>Title 10</h2>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
            <div class="description">
              <h2>Title 11</h2>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where missing `grid-cloumn`. check snippet.

```css
ul.posts {
  display: grid;
  padding-left: 0px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  justify-content: between;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

ul.posts li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: "g1";
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/13;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: "g2";
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/7;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: "g3";
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 7/13;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 3/4;
  grid-column: 1/5;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 3/4;
  grid-column: 5/9;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 3/4;
  grid-column: 9/13;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(7) {
  grid-row: 4/5;
  grid-column: 1/7;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(7) div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(7) div:nth-child(1) img {
  width: 100% !important;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(7) div:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row: 5/6;
  grid-column: 1/7;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(9) {
  grid-row: 4/6;
  grid-column: 7/13;
  background: #000;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(9) img {
  height: 800px;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(10) {
  grid-row: 6/7;
  grid-column: 1/13;
}

ul.posts li:nth-child(11) {
  grid-row: 7/8;
  grid-column: 1/13;
}

ul.posts img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="posts">
  <li>
    <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Title 3</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Title 4</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Title 5</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Title 6</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Title 7</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Title 8</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Title 9</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Title 10</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="featured-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
    <div class="description">
      <h2>Title 11</h2>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. It somewhat fixed it. Any idea how to get the far right column to stretch so that it's full height?

Comment: Glad that helped. which right column you are talking so i can check? also please do accept & up vote the answer.

Comment: The one with the heading 'Title 9 ' . As you can see in the design, it's supposed to stretch all the way down.

Comment: its working fine i added background color and see its goes till end. check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

use this span grid-column: 1 / span 6; for

```
<li style="
    grid-column: 1 / span 6;
">
            <div class="featured-image" style="
    flex: 0.6;
"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300"></div>
            <div class="description">
              <h2>Title 7</h2>
              <p>Description</p>
            </div>
          </li>
```

this code help to built same like this picture : [image]....